# To calculate the result of a formula

Tags: c

I need to find out the solution of the expression presented on the picture (110), but can't define the exact formula which would satisfy the conditions.

[image]

That's the code I have, but it seems wrong and not finished:

```
int n = 1, i = 1, x = 1;
float j, k, z, result;
 while (i<51)
    {
            z = n+2;
            x = z+2;
            k = 1./x;
            n+=2;
            j = 1./z+k;
            i++;
    }
 result = 1./(1+j);
 printf("\nThe result is: %f", result);
 }
```

I would be very grateful for pointing out the mistakes!

Comment: I don't think this loop does what the series requires. Short of a recursive solution, or a stack you might not be able to compute this.

Comment: This needs to be evaluated from the bottom up. Find `x0 = 103`, `x1 = 101 + 1/x0`, `x2 = 99 + 1/x1` etc.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: What is n, i, x, j, k and z? Some better names would make the code much easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Working from inside to outside, each step is the reciprocal of `i` plus the previous step, where `i` runs from 103 to 1 in steps of −2, and we start with a “previous step” of 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    double x = 0;
    for (int i = 103; 1 <= i; i -= 2)
        x = 1/(i + x);
    printf("%g\n", x);
}
```

Comment: The for loop should include `i==1`.